# Attempting to preemptively disqualify retort

Tags: idiom

If I were to say:

> The sky is falling! It undeniably false to claim that I am overreacting, as my detractors are sure to do.

Is there a common Latin phrase that encapsulates that, the tactic or practice of preemptively attempting to discredit rational response to an irrational point of view?

Apologies if this is unclear, I'm having a hard enough time attempting to put this in words in English.  Thanks

Comment: I've heard "poisoning the well" as a term for this in English, in that you're pre-emptively attacking the source.